# Ajustar height de los div al mismo tamaño en bootstrap

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap

En mi pagina estoy haciendo una seccion de productos usando bootstrap donde en general voy a poner 4 productos por fila, el problema es que cuando el nombre del texto es mas grande el div crece pero los div de al lado se mantienen igual, **me gustaria que tener el mismo tamano de divs por fila aunque el nombre del producto sea mayor.**

Ejemplo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.cs.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <row>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="grid_1_4">

                        <div class="picture">
                            <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/4f1486b7c4384522db07c2d9090682f2.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        </div>

                        <h3>Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge  </h3>

                        <div class="price_details">
                            <p><span class="money">2100 </span></p>
                            <p><button class="btn btn-default">Agregar al carrito</button></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="grid_1_4">

                        <div class="picture">
                            <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/4f1486b7c4384522db07c2d9090682f2.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        </div>

                        <h3>Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge extra plus extra plus extra plus  </h3>

                        <div class="price_details">
                            <p><span class="money">2100 </span></p>
                            <p><button class="btn btn-default">Agregar al carrito</button></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </row>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.grid_1_4{
    text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #EEE;
}

.picture{
    height: 200px;
}

.picture img{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ¿Entonces si uno crece mucho los demás deben crecer al mismo tamaño del más grande o quieres limitar un tamaño fijo para todos?

Comment: @ReneLimon Hola me gustaria que si uno crece los demas tambien crezcan y se nivelen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){//ACCION CUANDO CARGUE LA PAGINA

  var altura_arr = [];//CREAMOS UN ARREGLO VACIO
  $('.grid_1_4').each(function(){//RECORREMOS TODOS LOS CONTENEDORES DE LAS IMAGENES, DEBEN TENER LA MISMA CLASE
    var altura = $(this).height(); //LES SACAMOS LA ALTURA
    altura_arr.push(altura);//METEMOS LA ALTURA AL ARREGLO
  });
  altura_arr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a}); //ACOMODAMOS EL ARREGLO EN ORDEN DESCENDENTE
  $('.grid_1_4').each(function(){//RECORREMOS DE NUEVO LOS CONTENEDORES
    $(this).css('height',altura_arr[0]);//LES PONEMOS A TODOS LOS CONTENEDORES EL PRIMERO ELEMENTO DE ALTURA DEL ARREGLO, QUE ES EL MAS GRANDE.
  });
});
```

Como estas usando Bootstrap deberías estar usando Jquery por lo que te dejo un código que te puede servir.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

> Te dejo un ejemplo con solo css y html, ahora depende de ti acoplarlo con bootstrap:

```css
.contenedor{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor .box{
  background-color: #bbb;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```